# Erro ao iniciar aplicação JSF no Apache - CDI BeanManager instance is not available in JNDI

Tags: java, primefaces, ubuntu, tomcat, cdi

Tenho uma aplicação em JSF + Primefaces que no ambiente de desenvolvimento roda sem problemas.
Porém na hora de dar deploy do .war no Tomcat, em produção, não consigo. O Erro que consta nos logs é:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDI BeanManager instance is not available in JNDI.
```

As referências a omnifaces no projeto são:

`import org.omnifaces.util.Faces;` (em alguns beans)

`<resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CombinedResourceHandler</resource-handler>` (faces-config)

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Versão Tomcat 8.8.42. 
SO: Ubuntu 16.04

**Stack do erro:**

```
SEVERE [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.omnifaces.ApplicationListener]
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.omnifaces.ApplicationListener.checkCDIAvailable(ApplicationListener.java:63)
        at org.omnifaces.ApplicationListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationListener.java:55)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4770)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5236)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.reload(HostConfig.java:1414)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1378)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1613)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1170)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1392)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1364)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDI BeanManager instance is not available in JNDI.
        at org.omnifaces.config.BeanManager.<init>(BeanManager.java:106)
        at org.omnifaces.config.BeanManager.<clinit>(BeanManager.java:49)
        ... 15 more
```

Comment: Provavelmente você possui libs conflitantes/duplicadas no classpath do servidor, sugiro validar as libs constantes no classpath, bem como as enviadas com sua aplicação

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Mas você pode explicar melhor como faço para localizar possíveis conflitos oi duplicidades?

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente você possui conflito entre as libs do seu projeto e as libs do servidor, isso pode acontecer por algumas razões:

1. Libs incompatíveis (diferentes libs onde as versões "não se conversam")
2. Mesma lib em versões diferentes (várias versões do JSF por exemplo)
3. Libs empacotadas no projeto, mas que já estão em alguma `shared lib` do servidor
4. ...

Esse trabalho de verificação de libs é bem chato, recomendo você realizar os seguintes procedimentos:

1. Verificar as libs sendo empacotadas no seu **WAR / EAR** - normalmente empacotadas no `WEB-INF/lib` da aplicação
2. Verificar as libs constantes no classpath do servidor - geralmente você pode visualizar as pastas constantes no classpath executando `echo $CLASSPATH`
3. Procurar libs conflitantes (versões diferentes, libs que deveriam ser `provided` pelo servidor mas estão sendo empacotadas no WAR...)

Boa sorte na empreitada :)